# Contacts.app command line interface

Tags: contacts

Is there a CLI front-end to the Contacts.app (formerly Address Book.app) database?

Example:

```
mycontacts --email '*@google.com' # to get Googlers
```

Answer (score 5):

The closest thing to a generic solution is the *CLI* package **[`contacts`](https://github.com/shanecelis/contacts)** *by [Shane Celis](https://github.com/shanecelis)*. The source can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/shanecelis/contacts), and is also available as a [formulae](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/contacts#default) on [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). The [homebrew package](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/contacts#default) can be installed using  with the following command:

> `brew install contacts`

---

There are other options that may also work for you. Contacts just [stores info in a sqlite database](http://krypted.com/mac-security/querying-address-bookapp-from-the-command-line/) so you can access it with the `sqlite` command. You could [create a custom script](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100130052524548) to accomplish a particular task if you want.

[Scott Stevenson](http://theocacao.com/) had a tool called [abtool](http://theocacao.com/document.page/210) up that was popular for a while, so you could try [searching through the source on GitHub](https://github.com/lukhnos/abtool). In particular, since the app by [Shane Celis](https://github.com/shanecelis) appears unmaintained (*while still functioning well*), there are some who are building [replacements](https://github.com/tgray/contacts).

Answer (score 3):

Contacts still has AppleScript support. You can see documentation for the supported properties and commands by opening its dictionary in AppleScript Editor.

`osascript -e 'tell app "Contacts" to properties of people where vcard contains "@gmail.com"'`

I didn't find a way to check the actual email fields using a single specifier.

```
set l to {}
tell application "Contacts"
    repeat with p in people
        repeat with e in (get value of emails of p)
            if contents of e ends with "@gmail.com" then set end of l to name of p
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
l
```

Comment: Thanks, upvoting because it's a solution to the actual query I requested but it isn't a generic solution so I won't accept just yet.